# Почему не работает функция do_shortcode только на главной странице(Wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form7, visual-composer

Не отображается форма на главной странице, пробовала по всякому, но данный пример считаю более наглядным в файле footer.php:

```html
<div style="background:black">
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[contact-form-7 id='2531' title='Контактная форма_copy']"); ?>
</div>
```

И на всех страницах форма работает хорошо, кроме главной, на главной она видна в Visual Composer и в режиме для админа.
Если смотреть код страницы, то на месте выполнения кода пусто, ни текста, ничего

Comment: Это, конечно, глупый совет, но я бы попробовал полностью убрать title в шорткоде.

Comment: Возможно не туда вставляете, пример с кодом правильный

Comment: Код подключается к footer.php, который подключается ко всем страницам сайта, но только на всех страницах, кроме главной он работает, а на главной нет. Возможно на главной странице нет объявления какой-нибудь глобальной или статической переменной? Кто-нибудь знает, какие-то глобальные переменные, связанные с contact form 7?

Comment: Также на этой страницы работают другие shotcode, а title убрать я попробовала, это не сработало

Comment: Попробуйте переназначить главную страницу на какую-нибудь др, так же попробуйте переключить статус страницы.

Comment: @АринаШаброва Visual Composer и тому подобные плагины - это зло

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в главной странице, а в типе блока, в котором находится форма. Я практически уверен, что вы её поместили в блок типа html. Visual Composer не обрабатывает шорткоды в таких блоках. Шорткоды работают только в текстовых блоках.

Comment: Не думаю, так как я пыталась добавить эту форму другим путём и в Visual Composer эта форма представлена отдельным элементом, но с ней точно та же проблема. Она видна в Composer, она видна для админа, а в штатном режиме не видна

Comment: К тому же как я писала выше, в html коде на её месте пусто, если я бы вставляла её текстом, то она была бы видна в виде текста.

Answer (score 0):

В общем во всем виноват был Plugin Organizer, спасибо комментатору, предложившему переназначить главную страницу, это натолкнуло на мысль.
Вывод: для нормального решения проблемы следует указывать все используемые плагины))